# Apply background image to AlertDilog

Tags: android, background, android-alertdialog

I want to display a menu in a different style for that I want give background image to `alertdialog`.

*Any tutorial or link which help me to achieve my goal.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, you can create an AlertDialog within a custom view, in that custom view only assign a background you want. Later set that view like AlertDialog custom view.
an example:
- A RelativeCustomLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_1"
    android:padding="10dip">
        ............
</RelativeLayout>
```

now, inflate this view and set like dialog custom view

```
protected void createCustomDialog(int drawable, String title, String message){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(WkActivity.this);
        View customDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_error_dialog, null);
        ((TextView)customDialog.findViewById(R.id.genericErrorDialogTitle)).setText(title);
        ((TextView)customDialog.findViewById(R.id.genericErrorDialogMessage)).setText(message);
        ((ImageView)customDialog.findViewById(R.id.genericErrorDialogIcon)).setImageResource(drawable);

        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(WkActivity.this).create();
        dialog.setView(customDialog);
        dialog.setButton(getText(R.string.listaBusquedasGuardadasNoResultDialogButton), onClickListener);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: yup...thanks for your reply but i already done it..it working well...thanks again