# set background image alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create a customized `AlertDialog` with `Buttons` and `RadioGroup`. I want to have a background image saved in my drawable for this `AlertDialog`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AutoGenerate.this);                    
alert.setTitle("Select color");
```

Is there any alternative option like `alert.setbackgrounddrawable(R.drawable.img)`?

Comment: You can create a custom dialog with a custom view.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5473058/420015) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281963/how-to-change-the-background-image-of-alertdialog) [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347545/android-change-custom-alertdialog-background)

Comment: You want to set the background in your custom alert dialog is that so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom dialog with custom view.

```
    Dialog d = new Dialog(AutoGenerate.this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog);// custom layour for dialog.
    Button thankyou = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.thankyou);
    d.show();
```

alertdialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dialog_layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
 >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/thankyou"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:text="hello"

    android:padding="5dp">

          </Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit :

```
    rb= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showAlertDialog();
        }

    });       

     public void showAlertDialog() {

        final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog);
        // Thank you Button Listener.
        final TextView tv = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final Button thankyou = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.thankyou);
        thankyou.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      tv.setText("Button Clicked");

                return true;
            }

        });

        d.show();
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, i am using this alert dialod pop up on click listener of a radio button, when try to plug in this code inside radiobutton.setonclicklistener, getting classcast exception, any idea?

Comment: if(selected_option.equals("No")|| selected_option.equals("NO")|| selected_option.equals("no"))
     {
      LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
      View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialog, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
      final CharSequence[] gender = {"Male","Female"};         
      Dialog d = new Dialog(AutoGenerate.this);
         d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         d.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);// custom layour for dialog.
         Button thankyou = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.thankyou);
         d.show();
     }

Comment: Hi, inside the layout, have a textview, if i access inside the dialog using findviewbyid and try to set the title, getting null pointer exception, any idea y so?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26557/discussion-between-bharath-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 2):

you can do that using Layout file. Check Code Below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```

dialog_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also use diffrent views in xml.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, getting classcast exception doing it, any idea y??

Comment: just cheange this line --->  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a relatively simple variant that works with an AlertDialog:

```
// your code above
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AutoGenerate.this);                    
alert.setTitle("Select color");
// first show the dialog, then access its window and there set the background
alert.show();
alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Icon to alert dialog like this

```
alert.setIcon(R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: icon yup, created, but wanted to create a background image, icon sets an image at the top

Comment: try using custom alert dialog

Comment: It's not background , it's icon.

Answer (score 0):

Check out for [Create a Custom AlertDialog in android](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/04/in-android-sometimes-we-want-to-display.html).