# How to set custom color to getWindows in Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want use custom dialog in my application and i should set custom color for `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable` method in dialog options. 
I write below codes, but not set my custom color :

```
passengerAcceptDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

How can i set custom color for `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable` ?

thanks all <3

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520086/set-background-image-alertdialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
passengerAcceptDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: show red line under this code : (R.color.colorPrimary)

Comment: did you import ColorDrawable class or R class ?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use an external library to get this done. One of such is 
https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.3.1'
}
```

Example of implementation is given in their documentation